# Implementing a JAAS page to a WAR file on JBOSS AS 7.1.1

Tags: authentication, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, jaas

I'm very new to web applications. I've been told that JBOSS 7.1.1 has an in-built JAAS system which can be enabled on my JBOSS configuration quite simply. However I'm having trouble trying to get this running, namely most internet searching I went through has just ended up with older versions of JBoss.

Does anyone have a step-by-step guide on how to implement a simple JAAS authentication screen on my WAR file in JBoss 7.1.1? Prefarbly using its h2 database. Thanks :)

Also - my machine has trouble with Eclipse, so I can't use any of Eclipse EE's nifty server running mechanisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it. For those of you in the future:

You need your own standard login/logout pages in jsp/html/whatever. You put that in your web.xml constraints. Then you add an xml file called "Jboss-web" and type in your security domain (the default AS 7 is called 'other'). Then lastly add users and roles using adduser.bat in config folder.

Comment: I came from future. Nice answer.